# $2xy''+y'+xy=0,\ x>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$2xy''+y'+xy=0, x>0$

I have to find a power series solution and the  radius of convergence.

**My solution:**

I know that

${y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}X^{\lambda+n}=a_{0}X^{\lambda}+a_{1}X^{\lambda+1}+a_{2}X^{\lambda+2}+\cdots}.$

${y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\lambda+n)a_{n}x^{\lambda+n-1}=\lambda a_{0}X^{\lambda-1}+(\lambda+1)a_{1}X^{\lambda}+(\lambda+2)a_{2}X^{\lambda+1}+\cdots}.$

${y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\lambda+n)(\lambda+n-1)a_{n}X^{\lambda+n-2}=\lambda(\lambda-1)a_{0}X^{\lambda-2}+\lambda(\lambda+1)a_{1}X^{\lambda-1}+(\lambda+2)(\lambda+1)a_{2}X^{\lambda}+\cdots}$

Then,

$2x(\lambda(\lambda-1)a_{0}X^{\lambda-2}+\lambda(\lambda+1)a_{1}X^{\lambda-1}+\cdots+(\lambda+n+1)(\lambda+n)a_{n+1}X^{\lambda+n-1})+1(\lambda a_{0}X^{\lambda-1}+\cdots+(\lambda+n+1)a_{n+1}x^{\lambda+n})+x(a_{0}X^{\lambda}+\cdots+a_{n}X^{\lambda+n})=0.$

Find the indicial equation:

$2\lambda(\lambda+1)+(\lambda+1)+0=0\impliesλ=-\frac{1}{2},\:λ=-1.$

Then the recurrence equation:

$a_{n+1}=\frac{-a_{n-1}}{2λ^{2}+2n^{2}+3λ+4nλ+3n+1}\implies a_{n+2}=\frac{-a_{n}}{2n^{2}+2λ^{2}+7λ+7n+4nλ+6},$ with $λ=-\frac{1}{2} \implies a_{n+2}=\frac{-a_{n}}{2n^{2}+5n+3}.$

Then,

$y_{1}(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-a_{n}}{2n^{2}+5n+3}),$
and  $λ=-1 \implies a_{n+2}=\frac{-a_{n}}{2n^{2}+3n+1}$

Then,

$$y_{2}(x)=x^{-1}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-a_{n}}{2n^{2}+3n+1}).$$

I have to find the  radius of convergence; how can I do that?

Comment: How did the index shift in $λ$ happen? You should get $2λ(λ-1)+λ=0$ from the coefficients of $a_0x^{λ-1}$, so that $λ=0$ and $λ=+1/2$ are the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to do so much computations. Note that if you write the ODE as: $y’’+a(x)y’+b(x)y=0$. In your case $a(x) = \frac{1}{2x}$ and $b(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. As $x a(x)$ is analytic in $x=0$ and $a(x)$ is not, we conclude that $x=0$ is a singular regular point. Therefore, at least, you can find a solution of the ODE which will be a Frobenius series (have you read the proof of this theorem, no?). But as $xa(x)$ and $x^2 b(x)$ are polynomials, seen as power series,they converge for all $x \in \mathbf R$. Therefore, if $y(x) = x^{m} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$  will converge for all $x \in \mathbf R$ (this is proved in the theorem I was mentioning above) and $y(x)$ will be well defined for all $x>0$. If you want the proof of the theorem I’m writing about, tell me, and I will add to the answer :)